# Adding controls at runtime in from derived class in MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, dialog, visual-c++

I have two classes.
class DialogBase is inherited from CDialog
class DialogDerived is inherited from DialogBase.

```
BOOL DialodDervied::OnInitDialog()
{
     CDialogBase::OnInitDialog();
     //Add Dynamic Control to Main Dialog from here
}
```

I want to dynamically add a check box in the Dialog (CDialogBase) when it is called through the derived class. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a member variable `CButton m_ctrl_chk`, override DialodDervied::OnCreate() and add code like

```
int DialodDervied::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    m_ctrl_chk.Create(_T("Checkmate"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,
        CRect(5, 5, 100, 20), this, 1234); // the 1234 value is the ID of the control

    return 0;
}
```

Use similar classes (`CEdit`, `CStatic`, `CButton`, ...) to create other type of controls in the same way.